# Graph API /beta/sharepoint endpoint does not work on Microsoft Graph Explorer App

Tags: azure, sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api, azure-active-directory

I have an Azure AD account managed by my organization. A 3rd-party organization has invited my account to view their SharePoint Online content, which is hosted on their Office365 SharePoint system. When I visit the SharePoint site in a browser, I am able to use it without issue.

However, when I go to the [Microsoft Graph API Explorer](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer#/) app with the same user and make a request to the SharePoint endpoint at `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/sharepoint/site` I get the following response:

```
Status Code: 500
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "Unable to resolve template token",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "0b354b5d-ceaf-48d9-adb8-b97a7dcf07ad",
            "date": "2017-01-12T23:02:25"
        }
    }
}
```

This issue occurs on the Graph API Explorer app, see screenshot:

[image: Graph API Explorer error]

**To be clear about my objectives**: I expect that if a 3rd party partner invite me to view their Office 365 SharePoint content (and I am able to successfully browse it on the SharePoint online site itself), then I should be able navigate the same content via the Microsoft Graph API.

One question that has come up is what link is being used to get my authentication token in this workflow. The request, which I captured from the browser's developer tools, is below. Note the appropriate use of the Sites.ReadWrite.All scope, which should grant the necessary permissions: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=id_token+token&scope=openid%20User.Read%20User.ReadWrite%20User.ReadBasic.All%20Mail.ReadWrite%20Mail.ReadWrite.Shared%20Mail.Send%20Mail.Send.Shared%20Calendars.ReadWrite%20Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared%20Contacts.ReadWrite%20Contacts.ReadWrite.Shared%20MailboxSettings.ReadWrite%20Files.ReadWrite%20Files.ReadWrite.All%20Files.ReadWrite.Selected%20Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder%20Notes.ReadWrite%20Notes.ReadWrite.All%20Notes.ReadWrite.CreatedByApp%20Notes.Create%20Tasks.ReadWrite%20Tasks.ReadWrite.Shared%20**Sites.ReadWrite.All**&client_id=de8bc8b5-d9f9-48b1-a8ad-b748da725064&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.io%2Fen-us%2Fgraph-explorer&state=e3777b0b-5be3-442a-bb78-a82422baf709&client-request-id=df0a7be7-de18-4881-873d-717a5783cde9&x-client-SKU=Js&x-client-Ver=2.0.0-experimental&nonce=bff18134-8121-424f-a1ce-0c6ad87b177c

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how the O365 account comes into play here. Both are technically Azure AD accounts by the way, one just has an O365 tenant configured while the other does not. Could you provide a little more detail re: how you authenticated and what endpoints you called?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT I added additional context regarding what I am trying to do, and how I authenticated. Does that help? Please let me know if any other details would help.

Comment: Not all requests are honored through the Graph API Explorer. It's only for dipping your toes. If you want to test the Graph API and have permissions through Azure AD (Entra AD), then you should just use Postman.